# Open accordion on click, close accordion on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made an accordion element from scratch with help from a tutorial (this is one of my first forays into jQuery), and the behavior I'd like is for accordion elements to open upon clicking, then, if open, close when clicked again. Here's what I've  got:

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp(300);
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown(300)
    return false
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<dl class="accordion">
<dt><a href="">Question</a></dt>
<dd>Answer</dd>
<dl>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion {  
   dt, dd {
      border-bottom: 0; 
      &:last-of-type {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
      }
      a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
   }
  dd {
     border-top: 0; 
     &:last-of-type {
       border-top: 1px solid white;
       position: relative;
       top: -1px;
     }
  }
}
```

*Also on jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/j1f341ku/*

Currently, when you click an already-open element, it closes and re-opens. How can I make it so when an already-opened element is clicked, it closes and does not reopen? Thanks in advance!

*(PS The suggestions I've found on here for similar problems typically provide solutions for accordions that are built differently.)*

*(PPS Long-time reader, first-time poster! Be gentle, sorry if I made any mistakes.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your Fiddle:

try 
https://jsfiddle.net/j1f341ku/4/

```
(function ($) {

    var $allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $allPanels.slideToggle(300);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Here is an updated fiddle that should fix your bug (I added 3 questions in the fiddle as example):
https://jsfiddle.net/j1f341ku/5/

Comment: jQuery variables should be prefixed with a '$' out of best practice so I added that to your variable as well as swapped a return false for e.preventDefault(). Hope this answered your question!

Comment: thank you so much, you're awesome! I'm brand new to jQuery, and I'm just trying to crash course my way through. Really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Of course! That is what we are here for, to give and receive help :)

Comment: uh oh, new bug: Now, if there are more than one accordion elements on the same page, and one is clicked, all of them open. Should I open a new question for this, or is there a different procedure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here? [https://jsfiddle.net/j1f341ku/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/j1f341ku/6/) @KrakenDev